# Set the first character of Name column always to capital [MsSQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My MsSQL databases look like this one
[image]

How to Capitalize character after dash in case Rick Smith-hopkins?
Look like this:

```
Rick Smith-Hopkins
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
      LEFT([Person], 1) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Person], 2, CHARINDEX(' ', [Person] + ' ') - 2)) 'name'
      ,LEFT(SUBSTRING([Person], CHARINDEX(' ', [Person]) + 1, LEN([Person])), 1) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Person], CHARINDEX(' ', [Person]) + 2, LEN([Person]))) 'full surname'

      ,LEFT(SUBSTRING([Person], CHARINDEX(' ', [Person]) + 1, LEN([Person])), 1) 
      + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Person], CHARINDEX(' ', [Person]) + 2, LEN([Person]))) 'surname 1st with -'

      ,LEFT([Person], 1) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Person], 2, CHARINDEX(' ', [Person] + ' ') - 2)) + ' ' +
      LEFT(SUBSTRING([Person], CHARINDEX(' ', [Person]) + 1, LEN([Person])), 1) 
      + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Person], CHARINDEX(' ', [Person]) + 2, LEN([Person]))) 'Person'

FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
```

Comment: Do this on client-side.

Comment: Add `malcolm mcdowell, conan o'brien, jonathan rhys-davies and carl van der walt` to the sample data. And `Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Jonathan Rhys-Davies and Carl van der Walt` as result!

Comment: which sql server version ??

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would required some scaller function that takes char(-), string_values as parameter. But let me try to handle this with `stuff()` function to replace with upper char

```
SELECT 
     stuff(name, charindex('-', name)+1, 1, 
             upper(substring(name, charindex('-', name)+1, 1))) name,
      ....
FROM table
```

Note : This would be limited to only one char(-) position.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ivan, you should handle this at client end only.

If you need to do this at database level, create a function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnConvert_TitleCase] (@InputString VARCHAR(4000) )  
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @Index INT  
DECLARE @Char CHAR(1)  
DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(255)  

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)  
SET @Index = 2  
SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, 1, 1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString,1,1)))  

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)  
BEGIN  
    SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)  
    IF @Char IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&','''','(')  
    IF @Index + 1 <= LEN(@InputString)  
BEGIN  
    IF @Char != ''''  
    OR  
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index + 1, 1)) != 'S'  
    SET @OutputString =  
    STUFF(@OutputString, @Index + 1, 1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index + 1, 1)))  
END  
    SET @Index = @Index + 1  
END  

RETURN ISNULL(@OutputString,'')  
END
```